# Python. Глобальные переменные для нескольких файлов

Tags: python, global-variables

Есть желание использовать Словарь в качестве глобальной переменной (наподобие $_SESSION в РНР)
Не могу получить значение словаря во 2 файле, который импортируется в первый.

file1.py

```
 global_session ={}
 global_session['param1']='test1'
 import file2.py
 print_test1()# тут все ОК
 file2.print_test2()# тут уже не ОК
 def print_test1():
     print(global_session)
```

file2.py

```
 #global global_session  не помогло
 def print_test2():
     print(global_session)
```

Как сделать список глобальным между несколькими файлами ? Globals() тоже не прокатило. Уже стал думать про создание класса с записью в .ini

Comment: почитайте, как импортируются модули в python (хотя бы в части названия файлов).

Answer (score 0):

думаю в твоем случае легче всего сделать файл global_vars.py в нем:

```
global_session ={}
```

после этого в file2.py делаем

```
import global_vars
```

и используем:

```
 def print_test2():
     global global_vars.global_session  # вроде и без этого сработает
     print(global_vars.global_session)
```

Вроде должно сработать.